# Pass parameter to jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to pass a string into my dialog like this:

```
    ('#buttonSaveRight').click(function () {
      if (!ErrorHandlingSaveDialog()) {
      return false;
      }
      var nr = "testdata1";

      $("#dialogSaveConfirmation").data('param', nr).dialog('open');
      return false;
    });
```

and recieve it like this:

```
$('#dialogSaveConfirmation').dialog(

    {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: "auto",
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var nr= $('#dialogSaveConfirmation').data('param');

                alert(nr); //this is just for testing if I recieved the data or not
                //etc
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way that I can pass data into my dialog?

Best regards Johan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/StMyA/

The above code is working fine on my end.

**JS:-**

```
$('#dialogSaveConfirmation').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: "auto",
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {
            var nr = $('#dialogSaveConfirmation').data('param');

            alert(nr);

        }
    }});

$("#dialogSaveConfirmation").data('param', "asdsa").dialog('open');
```